# fail2ban not detecting ssh failures on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, sshd, fail2ban

I've installed fail2ban on CentOS 7 and added jail.local:

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
```

When I try a bad ssh login, I get a log entry in /var/log/secure like this:

```
Jun  5 11:09:40 arsenal sshd[32595]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.202 port 61745 [preauth]
```

But nothing appears in fail2ban log unless I set it to DEBUG:

```
2019-06-05 11:09:40,893 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [32110]: DEBUG   Read systemd journal entry: '2019-06-05T11:09:40.893324arsenal sshd[32595]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.202 port 61745 [preauth]'
```

Even if I try this bad login many times in a row, it's not blocking anything:

```
# fail2ban-client status sshd
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed: 0
|  `- Journal matches:  _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service + _COMM=sshd
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned: 0
   `- Banned IP list:
```

Comment: What is the matching RE for triggering from that error message?

Comment: @roaima you're right, I meant to say jail.local

Comment: I did not set a filter. The default is to use the section name, in this case sshd. Looking at that filter, it does not match "Permission denied" so I guess that answers the question.  Seems strange that this would not be included in the defaults.

Comment: The line you have shown does not actually show an authentication failure.  It shows the SSH client disconnected without successfully logging in.  It might not be a bad thing to filter for these and block them, but I don't believe fail2ban is regularly configured to catch this.

Comment: You're right, I'll make a pull request.  It's actually a shame sshd doesn't log this better.  The attacker gets more info: `root@192.168.1.1: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`